# Run failed (QT)

Tags: c++

I'm using QT.
I have two classes, one inherited from the other one. The issue is when I add an new attribute (specifically either string or Qstring) even if I don't use it in any method

I've got the following message when  I execute my program:
RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,819, total time: 22s)

Thanks

Comment: Get we get a code sample ? What environment are you using ? Visual Studio ? Our magic ball is out for maintenance

Comment: Can you post the relevant part of your program? We can't help debug code that we can't see...